# Supporting og:locale:alternate

Tags: facebook-opengraph

We have a site that supports multiple locales, but currently as most of our requests are routing through the Swedish data centre, all of our opengraph metadata is coming back in Swedish.

I've updated our code to look for the X-Facebook-Locale request header and fb_locale query param and set the locale of the site based upon that. I've also added meta properties of all of the locales that our site supports.

The site is:

http://mixrad.io/mixes/seeded/?artists=Madonna%2CSheryl%20Crow%2CKylie%20Minogue&s=fb8e5e45-a82c-4577-a01a-81ab358a5a81

And our opengraph tags are:

```
<meta name="description" content="MixRadio. It’s like having your own personal radio station. #MixRadio">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="MixRadio"/>

<meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="de_AT"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="de_CH"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="de_DE"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_AU"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_CA"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_GB"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_IE"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_IN"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_SG"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_US"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_ZA"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="es_ES"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="es_MX"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fi_FI"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_CA"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_CH"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="id_ID"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="it_IT"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="nb_NO"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="nl_NL"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="pl_PL"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="pt_BR"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="pt_PT"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="ru_RU"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="sv_SE"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="th_TH"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="tr_TR"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="vi_VN"/>
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="zh_CN"/>

<meta property="twitter:card" content="summary"/>
<meta property="twitter:site" content="@MixRadio"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="MixRadio. It’s like having your own personal radio station."/>
<meta property="twitter:description" content="MixRadio. It’s like having your own personal radio station."/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Madonna,Sheryl Crow,Kylie Minogue"/>
<meta property="twitter:title" content="Madonna,Sheryl Crow,Kylie Minogue"/>
<meta property="twitter:image:src" content="http://asset.ent.nokia.com/asset/artists/200x200/372444.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://asset.ent.nokia.com/asset/artists/200x200/372444.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg"/>
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200"/>
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="music.radio_station"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mixrad.io/gb/en/mixes/seeded/?s=fb8e5e45-a82c-4577-a01a-81ab358a5a81"/>
<meta property="og:audio" content="http://www.mixrad.io/gb/en/mixes/seeded/?s=fb8e5e45-a82c-4577-a01a-81ab358a5a81"/>
<meta property="og:audio:type" content="audio/vnd.facebook.bridge"/>
```

When it's scraping from the Swedish data centre, the "og:locale" is sv_SE.

Now I've put all the og:locale:alternate properties in, the facebook debugger gives me this message:

Object at URL 'http://www.mixrad.io/se/sv/mixes/seeded/?s=47a36fcd-235b-4b20-9088-6f89353a9728' of type 'music.radio_station' is invalid because the given value 'de_at' for property 'og:locale:alternate' could not be parsed as type 'enum'.

Is anyone able to help me figure out how to get our metatags rendering in the correct language for a user?

Thanks

Update:
The 'de_at' enum problem is caused by the fact that Facebook doesn't support that locale, removing locales that facebook doesn't support has got rid of that particular error, but everything is still turning up in Swedish.

Comment: Actually it scrapes it as en_US through Facebook's debugger tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't support every locale, here's their list of which ones they do: https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml

To my knowledge, Facebook initially scrapes your site without specifying a locale, then scrapes once per locale your meta tags indicate you support. As you've mentioned, you'll need to dynamically change the content attribute of each meta tag when your sever sees that X-Facebook-Locale header or their query parameter.

You're in charge of how you render your page, you probably want to be using the headers sent in requests from your users to determine language. Facebook doesn't look at the content of the page if you have opengraph locale support, it just looks at the meta tags and caches what it finds to display to its users within Facebook when rendering previews.